# Stop process using CancellationToken

Tags: c#, background-service, system.diagnostics, cancellation-token, worker-service

I need to run different instances of a Worker Service (`BackgroundService`): same code but different configuration.
The number of instances and the start and stop of every instance will change during the running process.

So my choice was to write 2 programs:

- `WorkerProgram`: the Worker Service
- `MainProgram`: manage (start and stop) of every different instance of `WorkerProgram`

Sample code of `WorkerProgram`:

```cs
var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddSingleton(new Instance { Id = int.Parse(args[0])});
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
    })
    .Build();

await host.RunAsync();

public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly Instance _instance;
    public Worker(Instance instance)
    {
        _instance = instance;
    }
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Running {}", _instance.Id);
            await Task.Delay(10000, stoppingToken);
            _logger.LogInformation("END");
        }
    }
}
```

`MainProgram` starts every `WorkerProgram` using

```cs
var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.Filename = "WorkerProgram.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = i.ToString();
process.Start();
```

so every Worker Service run in a different process.

But when it needs to stop them, the command

```cs
process.Kill();
```

will Kill the process in the middle of run.

How can I stop the process in a better way (eg. using CancellationToken)?

Thank you!

My current (bad) solution is to create a placeholder file for every BackgroundService. And check the existence of the file at every cicle.

Comment: that's pretty strange: you're going to creare a "worker process", which runs a background task. Why not create a single process, where the "main" is the process itself and the worker is the background service?

Comment: @MarioVernari I previously tried your suggestion, but every background service need a different set of DI, not the same.

Comment: not very clear: if you create two different classes (e.g. Worker1 and Worker2), both deriving from `BackgroundService`, what's the problem in having different injections?

Comment: @MarioVernari I've one class `:BackgroundService` that use some services from DI (some of these services are Singleton that keeps some data). At runtime I need to run different instances of the same `BackgroundService` (only at runtime I know how many instances). Every instance has different configuration that reflect to DI (eg. AddDbcontext, Singletons, etc.), so I thought to put these definitions in the `WorkerProgram`.

Answer (score 0):

untested, but:

```cs
cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
process.Start();
using (cancellationToken.Register(static state => {
    try {
        (state as Process)?.Close(); // or Kill, or both; your choice
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // best efforts only
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}, process))
{
    await process.WaitForExitAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

The `Register` here will deal with killing the process in the cancellation case; if the external process exits before then, we will unregister via the `using` after the `WaitForExitAsync`, and won't attempt to kill it.

Comment: `Kill` isn't for hard-stopping processes? I'd rather use `Close` for a graceful way, instad.

Comment: @MarioVernari I was using the OP's mention of `Kill`, but: I've clarified

Comment: no problem. I only remember to have read somewhere to use `Kill` only when even the fire estinguisher would fail!

Comment: @MarcGravell Thank you! But I've a problem understanding how to use your code because at the `WaitForExitAsync` line the execution stop and wait for the process to close. So I cannot start other processes. I've to run your code in different threads?

Comment: @Stefano well, this isn't necessarily a thread - we're using async-await as part of unregistering in the success case; you could use `Task.Run` to invoke it as an execution

Comment: @MarcGravell Maybe I've implemented in the wrong way, but my Worker keep closing/killing in the middle of the execution: i see the "Running..." log but not the "END" when the process is closed. I have used your code with `await Task.Run(() => { process.WaitForExitAsync(cancellationToken); });` to not block the execution.